# Buenas tardes, solicito la ayuda para la compilación del código fuente de minix 1

Tags: unix

desde la consola instalar MINIX1, sin una ISO, solamente con los archivos .c tengo entendido se hace con makefiles, pero no se como usarlo o compilar, esto en una maquina virtual, yo uso virtual box.

Dejo el link de los archivos de minix1.

https://github.com/gdevic/minix1
GRACIAS!!

Comment: El titulo es que me ayuden a compilar minix1 sin una ISO 
ya que no tiene código como tal, tengo entendido son comandos.

Comment: Revisaste ya el [readme](https://github.com/gdevic/minix1/blob/master/doc/read_me) en el proyecto que nos compartiste?

Comment: asi es, pero no aparece como compilar el codigo fuente de minix1

Answer (score -1):

Creo que el camino pasa por usar las instrucciones de la wiki oficial para hacer [cross compiling](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:crosscompiling) desde otro sistema Unix, por ejemplo.

Comment: Ok, checaré si es posible hacerlo con minix 1, ya que la wiki solo muestra minix 3, y pues tiene archivos distintos creo yo, pero lo intentare, gracias por tomarte el tiempo